# Generate random postive/negative Number

Tags: actionscript-3

How do you generate a Number that is randomly postive or negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide your low and high numbers as parameters to this function

```
function randomNumber(low:Number=0, high:Number=1):Number {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate a random number in the range [0, n] and subtract n/2.

Answer (score 1):

```
private function randomize( amount:Number ):Number
{ 
    return ( ( Math.random() - .5 ) * 2 ) * amount;
}
```

Comment: in the end, it's just a syntax question ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
var no1:Number;
var no2:Number;

no1 = Math.random() - .5;
if (no1> 0) {
   no2 = no1 + (1 - no1);
}else {
   no2 = no1 - (1 + no1);
}

trace(no2);  // returns either 1 or -1
```