# AS3 Calling Math.random in a scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, random

So, i'm trying to make a game where asteroids travel around randomly, but when I put my Math.random function outside of my function, it onlygives 1 value 1 time, and does not repeat each time the asteroid = 0. If I put it in my function, it just constantly updates and sends my asteroid flying around randomly. Any help? 
EDIT: Sorry if I was unclear, i've been up all night. I am looking to make my asteroid move on a random path across the screen, then pick another path randomly and move on that path, and this should happen every time x>1024 and y>768

```
import flash.events.Event;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, massGain);
stop();

var math1:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*20-10);
trace(math1);

function massGain(e:Event)
{


Mouse.hide();

Cosmo.x = mouseX;
Cosmo.y = mouseY;

Asteroid5.x = Asteroid5.x + math1;
Asteroid5.y = Asteroid5.y + math1;
if(Asteroid5.x >1024){
Asteroid5.x = 0;
}
if(Asteroid5.y > 768){
Asteroid5.y = 0;
}



}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve, I did not understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, i've been up all night. I am looking to make my asteroid move on a random path across the screen, then pick another path randomly and move on that path, and this should happen every time x>1024 and y>768

Comment: So you want smooth movement, and whenever it touches the end of the screen, it starts on another random movement path?

Comment: Exactly. And it should move in a straight line, no curves or jumps or anything.

Comment: Ok understood, let me write the code, wait.

Comment: If you want to get into this sort of stuff, you should start learning how to use vectors. I don't mean vector graphics, but mathematical vectors. This book is great to learn how to move things by code: http://www.amazon.com/Foundation-Actionscript-3-0-Animation-Making/dp/1590597915/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1362938369&sr=1-1&keywords=animation+code+flash

Comment: Man, you're awesome. Thanks, I was getting hung up on resets with random movement and this is helping!

Comment: @Pier Graphical Vectors, AS3 Vector.<Foo> and mathematical vectors. So many vectors. I bet there are a few more meanings to this term that I do not know.

Comment: @AnkurSharma I don't think anyone would confuse a Vector<T> with a math vector... just google "math vector" and look at the results. Do you see any reference to any other type of vector than Euclidean vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import flash.events.Event;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, massGain);
stop();

var speedX = Math.floor(Math.random()*20-10);
var speedY = Math.floor(Math.random()*20-10);

function massGain(e:Event)
{


Mouse.hide();

Cosmo.x = mouseX;
Cosmo.y = mouseY;

Asteroid5.x = Asteroid5.x + speedX;
Asteroid5.y = Asteroid5.y + speedY;
if(Asteroid5.x >1024||Asteroid5.x<0){
speedX = -speedX;
}
if(Asteroid5.y > 768||Asteroid5.y<0){
speedY = -speedY;
}
}
```

Try this.

Comment: @user2072135 not more randomized really, but whenever the object touches the corner, it will bounce right back. The speed value will remain the same, the direction will change. If you want more random values, you can call the Math.random inside the if statement, like the other answerer's suggestion.

Comment: Also, this answer has a random speed vector for both x and y as opposed to one vector for both in the orignal code, which increases variability greatly.

Answer (score 0):

use this!

```
import flash.events.Event;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, massGain);
stop();

// random value to start of with
var math1:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);//20-10 doesnt make sense .. its 10

function massGain(e:Event)
{
        Mouse.hide();

        Cosmo.x = mouseX;
        Cosmo.y = mouseY;


        if(Asteroid5.x >1024){
        Asteroid5.x = 0;
        math1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);// new random Value
        trace(math1);
        }
        if(Asteroid5.y > 768){
        Asteroid5.y = 0;
        math1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);// new random Value
        }

        Asteroid5.x = Asteroid5.x + math1;
        Asteroid5.y = Asteroid5.y + math1;

}
```

Comment: Ah, cool! My main source of confusion was if I could just call my 1 math function multiple times and get different numbers, or if I had to write multiple times. This answers my question, thanks!

Comment: NP. then pls mark as correct answer, thats how this site works.

Comment: Oh, sure thing (Sorry, i'm still kinda new here.)

Comment: One more question, how would I modify the math. random code so the random number can be negative also, that way the asteroid is not just coming from the left side of the screen?

Comment: use this function postet here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926662/generate-random-postive-negative-number